# How to do case-insensitive "OrderBy" in Azure search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I was trying to search Documents using the Azure Search Service REST API, with ORDER BY field populated with a certain field on my search index model:

The Request Body format is like this according to :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents

```
{  
     "count": true | false (default),  
     "facets": [ "facet_expression_1", "facet_expression_2", ... ],  
     "filter": "odata_filter_expression",  
     "highlight": "highlight_field_1, highlight_field_2, ...",  
     "highlightPreTag": "pre_tag",  
     "highlightPostTag": "post_tag",  
     "minimumCoverage": # (% of index that must be covered to declare query successful; default 100),  
     "orderby": "orderby_expression",  
     "scoringParameters": [ "scoring_parameter_1", "scoring_parameter_2", ... ],  
     "scoringProfile": "scoring_profile_name",  
     "search": "simple_query_expression",  
     "searchFields": "field_name_1, field_name_2, ...",  
     "searchMode": "any" (default) | "all",  
     "select": "field_name_1, field_name_2, ...",  
     "skip": # (default 0),  
     "top": #  
   }
```

As the "orderby", I put it like this:
"orderby":"Title asc"
where "Title" is a field in my search index model.

The result returned is sorted based on Title asc, but it's case sensitive, that's all A-Z records come before a-z records. Is there a way that I can make this order by case-insensitive? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Currently, there's no built-in way to do case-insensitive sorting.** One way to do this is to add a field to your index with case-normalized values and sort by that field.

Please vote for this [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/8c74f607-0325-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8)<sup>[original](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803211838/https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328658-case-insensitive-sorting-for-string-fields)</sup> suggestion to promote this feature to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can set normalizer "lowercase" for your field. This normalizer is built-in in the service. Indexer will index your data like being lower cased. When querying query your index casing doesn't matter. You will get the same result for lower or uppercases.
What is pity, is the fact that using beta version of Azure.Search.Documents nuget package NormalizerName property can be set, but in stable version of the package NormalizerName is not present.